# How to call a php function from html (local based)

Tags: php, html, function, call

I'm new to PHP and HTML, so I'm asking you guys to help me: I'm trying to call a function from an external .php file to echo a header  title from a .html file. If this is even possible, how can I call it? Thank you a lot.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking here, can you show us some code to demo what you are trying to do please

Comment: There's not relevant code yet. I just created and index.html file with some stuff in it, a PHP file with an echo function. Our prof wants us to echo elements like a title from the PHP file. I have no clue how to call this functions from the HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Echo Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo 'Hi this is a tilte'; ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo 'Hi this is a body'; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

or you could do something like this:

```
<?php 
    function title() {
        return echo 'Hi I am a title';
    } 
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Function Echo Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?php return title(); ?></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```